# Why my Javascript test using Jasmine fails

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine-jQuery to unit test my Javascript but am having trouble getting this test to work. I need to confirm that when user scrolls the page far enough one of the panels becomes sticky. This happens in `Lozenges.makeFixed()` method and so I need to confirm this method gets called on window `scroll`. My test fails miserably and not sure what am I doing wrong. The src code is:

```
mycompany.singleJob=(function($,undefined) {

    // some code goes here Lozenges object etc.

    function init() {
    // more code here

    $(window).on("scroll.singleJob",function(e)
    {           
        // at this point if its mobile device simply exit

        if(mycompany.framework.isMobile()) return;

        // we also need to make first panel sticky
        // check if nav is getting out of visible area. it means it should be sticky

        if(!LozengesPanel.fixed && $(window).scrollTop()>104)
        {

            LozengesPanel.makeFixed();

        }
        else if(LozengesPanel.fixed && $(window).scrollTop()<104)
        {

            LozengesPanel.makeStatic();
        }
    });

    // more code here

}

    // more code here

    return {
        init:init
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Now, I want to test that when user scrolls the window past certain point `LozengesPanel.makeFixed();` will be called. I have this test suite but it keeps failing.

```
describe("SingleJob page", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
    mycompany.singleJob.init();

});


it("panel sticks to top when page scrolled down", function() {

         spyOn(mycompany.singleJob.LozengesPanel, "makeFixed");
         $(window).scrollTop(500);


            expect(mycompany.singleJob.LozengesPanel.makeFixed).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

});
```

I would think that `$(window).scrollTop(500)` should trigger scroll so why `expect` line fails?